# linux script command explanation

Tags: command-line, scripts

When I read a script of makefile, I meet with the following linux script command:

```
mv obj/*.o .  2>/dev/null
```

What does this command mean? I understand `mv obj/*.o .` means that all the files with suffix `o` in the `obj` folder will be moved to the current folder. What does `2>` mean? When they are combined together, what is purpose? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at [output redirection (Bash)](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html). 2 stands for 'stderr', the error output. By redirecting it to `/dev/null`, you're discarding it to oblivion. Regular output, 'stdout' or 1 is still shown (in your terminal by default), though.

Basically, this is just silencing error output of the `mv` command.

A snippet from the above link explains it more general:

```
COMMAND_OUTPUT >
  # Redirect stdout to a file.
  # Creates the file if not present, otherwise overwrites it.

  ls -lR > dir-tree.list
  # Creates a file containing a listing of the directory tree.
[..]
1>filename
  # Redirect stdout to file "filename."
1>>filename
  # Redirect and append stdout to file "filename."
2>filename
  # Redirect stderr to file "filename."
2>>filename
  # Redirect and append stderr to file "filename."
&>filename
  # Redirect both stdout and stderr to file "filename."
```

Answer (score 0):

Btw, sometimes you might want to prevent displaying on the screen but might want to capture it on a file. If that's the case you might do something like this:

```
mv obj/*.o . > move.log 2>&1
```